# Check if file content exists with powershell

Tags: powershell

Apoligies in advance if my question isn't clear or not formatted correctly. This is my first time ever posting here.

I have a simple powerhshell script that copies files from one folder to another, if the file doesn't already exist in the destination folder. However, my current issue is that while the files have different names, they can have the exact same content. I want the script to be able tell if the file content already exist in the destination folder and if so, don't do anything. IF the file content doesn't already exist in the destination, then it copies the file. Any help is appreciated.

```
$date = get-date
$path = "path1"
$destination = "path2" 
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $path)) {
If($file.LastWriteTime -gt $date.date) 
{ 
    #Test to see if the file already exists in the destination.
    if (!(Test-path (join-path $destination $file.name)))
    {
       Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $destination
    }
}

}
```

Comment: see `get-help Get-FileHash -Examples`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to have to go with what Kory Gill posts.

Use get-filehash to test the hashes of the files to see if they match or not..even if their file names are different.  It hashes the contents.  Keep in mind that any difference will create a different hash.  Any space or character that is in one file and not the other will produce a completely different hash.  But, if you are looking for exact matches this works best.  use -Algorithm sha256 since sha1 and md5 or declared not secure (possible to get collisions), though it might be hard with Sha1 to get a collision still today unless you are really trying.

```
if((Get-FileHash -Path <file1> -Algorithm SHA256).Hash -ne (Get-FileHash -Path <file1> -Algorithm SHA256).Hash)
{
    "Copy the file"
}
```